# Why doesn't the output of the command `cal` have the day highlighted?

Tags: bash, variables, wallpaper

I need that the output of the command `cal` stay highlighted in a variable in order print it into a wallpaper so I can disable the calendar software to save resources of a low spec computer. How can I make the `cal` output stay highlighted?

Comment: The `cal` command just sends a sequence `0x5f08` before the character
to be highlighted. The terminal interprets the sequence and displays
the B/W reversed character on the screen. If you want to highlight the
character on the wallpaper, you need to add the attribute which can be
interpreted by the wallpaper software or modify the bitmap of the character before rendering.

Comment: `cal` determines whether or not to use highlighting based on whether its standard output is a terminal or not. At the least the version I have has no way to forcing `cal` to use highlighting for a non-terminal output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```sh
cal -h | sed 's/ \('"$(date +%_d)"'\) /{\1}/'
```

outputs

```
     June 2021
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
     { 1} 2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30
```